# How to redirect user to client app after logging out from identity server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to redirect user to the same client after he logged out from that client. So if i have lets say 5 clients on one identity server, i want users to be able to log out from one client and be on that same client but logged out.

The one thing i have tried is to use PostLogoutRedirectUri in AccountController in quickstart, but the value is always null. Workaround that i found is to manually set PostLogoutRedirectUri, that works fine if you have only one client on the server, but not so much if I have multiple. Is there any way to know which client has been "logged out"?

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
    {
        // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
        var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

        if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            // delete local authentication cookie
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            // raise the logout event
            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
        }

        // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
        if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
        {
            // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
            // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
            // complete our single sign-out processing.
            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

            // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
        }


        vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:56582";
        return Redirect(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
    }
```

My Client

```
 new Client
                {

                    ClientId =  "openIdConnectClient",
                    ClientName = "Implicit Client Application Name",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "role",
                        "customAPI.write"
                    },

                    RedirectUris = new List<string>{ "http://localhost:56582/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>{ "http://localhost:56582" },
                   // FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:56582/signout-oidc"

                }
```

Comment: PostLogoutRedirectUri is something you configure per client, it should not be null if you configure it. You don't show your code how your clients are setup.

Comment: I ve updated info with client code

Comment: I have an open source integration with IdServer [here](https://www.cloudscribe.com/identityserver-integration) that does redirect correctly after logout. [source code here](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe) My idserver logout action accepts a logoutId which I use with IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetLogoutContext(logoutid) and that returns for me the client PostLogoutRedirectUri.

Comment: why is my postlogoutredirecturi null when i set it in my client?

Comment: are you sure you are getting a value for logoutid? Maybe look at my code [here](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe/blob/bd483917025d3e6213615943e7f2b638a722226b/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L960-L996) and [here](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe/blob/bd483917025d3e6213615943e7f2b638a722226b/src/cloudscribe.Core.IdentityServerIntegration/CloudscribeIntegration.cs#L57-L69)

Comment: yeap, there is logoutid, vm is also not null,but redirecturi is still null

Comment: are you using IIdentityServerInteractionService to get it? You don't show code for BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not supposed to set the uri manually. Actually the default logout method from the IdentityServer samples works fine.

When you try the [3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication) sample project, you'll see `PostLogoutRedirectUri` is not null and the redirection works (but not automatically).

The reason why `PostLogoutRedirectUri` is `null` in your case is probably because the *id_token* is not preserved. In [MvcClient.Startup](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs#L28) make sure you add this line:

```
options.SaveTokens = true;
```

That will preserve the tokens in a cookie.

In order to automatically redirect back to the client, make a few adjustments to the sample code. In IdentityServer [AccountOptions](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountOptions.cs#L16) set

```
AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = true;
```

In the [AccountController.Logout](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L195) method add the following lines:

```
if (vm.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut && 
               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri))
    return Redirect(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
```

Just before the last line:

```
return View("LoggedOut", vm);
```

When you run the sample again you should see that the user is now automatically returned to the client after logout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did all that you said but it still redirects me to identity server, and when i debug      vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri       is still null.

Comment: Try `PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:56582/signout-callback-oidc" }`.

Comment: yeap sorry, i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: The  AccountOptions link is broken:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountOptions.cs#L16 is broken.